# Extend PHP form with required fields and validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, required-field

I need help with extending my PHP script. I need required fields and a validation for an email field within a sign-up-form.

This is my Code, I tried to use different if and echo codes but nothing works within this.

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
$from = $email;

$to = "xy@gmail.com";
$subject = "SIGN UP";

$emailbody = "";
$emailbody .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";

$header = "";
$header .= "From:" . $from . " \n";
$header .= "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8";

// Sending message
$success = mail($to, $subject, $emailbody, $header);

if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=confirmation_signup.html\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}
?>
```

The code works, emails get delivered, but the form shouldn't be successful if the fields aren't filled in. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

it appears that email is the only thing you're collecting from the POST, so just check if that's [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) first, and [validate it](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp):

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)){

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $from = $email;

  $to = "xy@gmail.com";
  $subject = "SIGN UP";

  $emailbody = "";
  $emailbody .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";

  $header = "";
  $header .= "From:" . $from . " \n";
  $header .= "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8";

  // Sending message
  $success = mail($to, $subject, $emailbody, $header);

  if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=confirmation_signup.html\">";
  }
  else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
  }
}
else echo "email required";
?>
```

And before it hits the server, you might help your user out by doing some client side validation first to make sure the [input is an email](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_form_input_types.asp), and [is required](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can check email field is not empty and then you can use `filter_var` to validate provided email.

Here is an example

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) )
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $from = $email;

    $to = "xy@gmail.com";
    $subject = "SIGN UP";

    $emailbody = "";
    $emailbody .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";

    $header = "";
    $header .= "From:" . $from . " \n";
    $header .= "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8";

    // Sending message
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $emailbody, $header);

    if ($success)
    {
        print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=confirmation_signup.html\">";
    }
    else
    {
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
    }
}
else print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
?>
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! But I've another problem - maybe you have a solution too...

Comment: @DietrichMöller What is it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed, but another problem appeared. The html form doesn't send the mail correctly. I tried six mail addresses. If someone submit the form, the mails are sometimes sent to the one - sometimes to the other - sometimes to no adress. I heard about not to use the regular mail () command. Can someone tell me about this?

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['message']) && (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $email;
$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "SUPPORT";

$emailbody = "";
$emailbody .= "Full name: " . $name . "\n";
$emailbody .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
$emailbody .= "Message: " . $message . "\n";

$header = "";
$header .= "From:" . $from . " \n";
$header .= "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8";

$success = mail($to, $subject, $emailbody, $header);

if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=de/confirmation.html\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=de/error.html\">";
}
}
else print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=de/error.html\">";
?>
```